# opening an xPage in the Notes 9 client

Tags: launch

We have an xPage application that now must be used in the Notes client.  It works great in Notes 8.5.3, and we can launch an xPage using the database properties.  But in Notes 9, this is a different story.
You can't launch an xPage in the Notes 9 Basic client.  It just isn't an option. So, I created a form with a link, that opens in the opening frameset.  It looks like this:  notes://server/path/database.nsf/home.xsp?openxpage
Again, this works perfectly in the Notes 853 client.  But in Notes 9 Basic client, the link does absolutely nothing.
How can we get the users to an xPage in the Notes 9 Basic client???

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your 8.5.3 client is not a standard client.  My understanding is you need eclipse to run xpages. The Notes Basic client does not have eclipse.